# add vue.js variable inside laravel route function parameter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I working with vue.js inside laravel blade ,
I want to parse my product id (vue.js variable) to laravel routing function parameter I tried more than solutions but it doesn't work like:

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.add', @{{this.productID}}) }}" method="POST">
```

please, help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, as PHP is Pre-processor, it will render first, JS doesn't execute before that.
Instead of that you can replace your value with pattern, and replace that pattern using JS.

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.add', ['__ID__']) }}" method="POST">
```

Now before submitting, you can read URL of action using JS and replace it with the value of your VueJS variable.

Comment: how can I replace it with js?

Comment: string replace.
`var1.replace("__ID__", this.id);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your vue variables in your blade file. What you should do is move your `<form>` inside a Vue component and use the variable there. And to be able to use your laravel named routes in `.vue` files you can use [this](https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy) package.